# How to find memory leaks in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

We are getting some memory leaks at point:

```
[UIView respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

but I cannot understand where I am missing an also I don't understand what it means that `[UIView respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance)`.

Comment: You might want to post the code where you instantiate the view that's causing the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build your app with mac+shift+a and it will show memory leaks..
and for more accurately find memory leaks use Instruments

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/WorkingWithInstruments/WorkingWithInstruments.html

Answer (score 0):

Enable NSZOMBIE to start with then use the allocation tools in instruments.

Comment: NSZombie finds zombies, the opposite of leaks

Comment: Look at his error, he has a memory leak. Zombie will point out what object he has over-released in allocations in intruments after you enable zombie.

Comment: Memory leak is when memory is not released. Zombies are when memory is over-released

Comment: leaks or not what I mean is he has an issue, he over-released an object something , whatever u want to call it, it is memory related and to solve it he needs to use instruments and enable zombie to find out what he over-released.

Answer (score 0):

Use XCode 4's analyze feature for basic leaks - it's very good.